# Empty ngOnInit/Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular application,when i generated new components the error "Unexpected empty constructor  @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function" and "Unexpected empty method 'ngOnInit' @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function" has been triggred.

This is my script:

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-header',
      templateUrl: './header.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
    })
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor() { 
        //
       }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        //
      }
    
    }
```

As you can see i tried to add // ,but the problem still persists.But for footer and header the same idea worked without problems.Can someone tell me what I am missing or what else i can do?

Comment: Remove the empty functions?

Comment: Why to remove them? This won't  give an impact on program? @R.Richards

Comment: It is not a compilation error but a linter error... change your linter settings

Comment: @Akxe i installed Eslint and  additional plugins + Prettier and Prettier-ESLint dependencies ,but it didnt help me so much ,the error didnt diseapear .

Comment: If you are not using them, you don't need them. Remove them and move on.

Comment: @R.Richards removing them i get " Class 'HeaderComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'.
  Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'HeaderComponent' but required in type 'OnInit'".

Comment: I will use this components as creating routes , after pressing a speciic word to be transfered to the new created window

Comment: Remove `implements OnInit`, too. Remove `OnInit` from the import too.

Comment: @R.Richards i deleted them and still got the same errors ,the error for OnInit didn't diseapear

Comment: You need to remove "implements OnInit" from `export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a compilation error. Eslint gives the error to force you to maintain code standards. If you want to use Eslint, But ignore 'no-empty-function' there are some ways. You can globally disable the error, or only in a file or only in a constructor etc.  You can use any of them -

create .eslintrc.json there add -

```
{
  "root": true,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

this config globally disables 'no-empty-function' rule. You can also allow this rule only in constructor. Replace the previous rules value with this -

```
"rules":{
   "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function":[
      "error",
      {
         "allow":[
            "constructors"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

If you simply want the rule for the specific line you will add this line -

```
 // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
```

above your functions.